# How do I construct a 4 sided 45 degree pyramid from four triangular planes ( open on bottom )

Tags: geometry, triangles, projective-geometry

I have two square mirrors, and I'm trying yo create a four sided 45 degree pyramid with as few cuts as possible. I'm trying to figure out how to design a 2d pattern that will result in the pyramid I desire. The mirrors I have are 10" x 10"

Answer (score 1):

You have to cut out four isosceles triangles with base $x$ and altitude $x/\sqrt2$. See picture below for a possible cutting pattern.

[image]

**EDIT.** Here's a way to get the triangles with only four cuts. Notice however that they are smaller than before.

[image]

Comment: looks like there is no way around making 5 cuts

Comment: You could rotate the pattern so that one side of a triangle lies along a side of the square, in order to make just four cuts, but the triangles would be smaller.

Comment: The second example, is pretty cool! although I think I will stick with the first